# How do I keep a formula when a new row is added?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I set an automation that when a form is submitted, a new row is added in **Google Sheets**, including a First Name and a Last Name cell. I have a Contact Name field with this formula: `=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(C9;" ";D9))`.

When a new row is created, the formula is not applied to the new Contact Name cell. What I found so far is using references that don't work with `CONCATENATE` like `(C:C; " "; D:D)`, and the ArrayFormula doesn't work either.

What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"header"; C2:C&" "&D2:D})
```

Comment: Substituting "header" for "Contact name"? Doesn't seem to work: https://i.imgur.com/l3OZICl.png

Comment: @AlejandroGoffa delete all you have in range A2:A. only then the formula will auto-populate the whole column